# Getting an object lined up with the x, y, or z axis again

Tags: interface

I got a model from [SketchUp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SketchUp), and imported it into Blender to modify it. It was just half the figure, meant in the end to be mirrored to have it be completed, and when I initially imported it into Blender it was lined up perfectly so that both the nose and tail were nicely aligned at x axis 0.

Through the course of working on it however I must have accidentally rotated it off center. I want to duplicate the left side so that I can mirror it and then merge these two halves, but I need to have that center loop of the figure uniformly on x axis 0. How do I get it squared up again?! [See how it's been tilted off center?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LALOn.jpg)

Comment: Andy, since Jerryno's answer solved your problem, please mark it as the "Accepted Answer".

Answer (score 6):

1. Close the shape with ngon:

   [image]
2. Add *Empty* to the scene, enable snapping, set to face, enable align orientation and snap the empty to the ngon:

   [image]
3. Parent the mesh to the empty: Select mesh, select empty, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
4. Reset the rotation of empty with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
5. Clear parent (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) and Keep the transform. Now your mesh is aligned with world coords.
6. Delete Empty, delete ngon, rotate mesh to the axis you want.

Comment: Why create a ngon, step 1 and 6 aren't necessary, can snap to edge.

Comment: @iKlsR what if the seam isn't completely flat? Best would be to add also step 7: scale the seam to 0.

Comment: That did it. Thanks for the very descriptive response.